# How to assign a filename with a pointer one?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I do have a function that I have created with a pointer as an argument.
That argument will be used to save at the end an image.
Every time when I would like to call that function with the desired parameter, I want that the saved image file would be with the specified name. I show you how:

```
void SaveImage(IplImage *img)
{
...
cvSaveImage("C:/img.png", img);
...
}
```

when calling the function: SaveImage(image1), I want to have an image on my C:/ whose name is image.png

Can you help me with that?

Comment: What's wrong with `cvSaveImage("C:/image.png", img);` !?

Comment: @M Everytime that I call cvSaveImage(blabla), blabla overwrites the old img.png and for me, I would like to keep that safe! Can you see it?

Comment: That question is almost completely incomprehensible, sorry. Are you asking how to *append* an image to an already saved one instead of overwriting it? Or do you want to create a new image whose name equals that of the variable that you pass into the function?

Comment: @Konrad You almost understood it, I want to create a new image whose name equals that of the variable that I pass into the function.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you can't answer this question with the only answer that is actually viable, because you get downvoted...

So, I'll rephrase my answer:

You need to pass two variables to SaveImage:

```
void SaveImage(const char *name, IplImage *img)
{
   ...
   cvSameImage(name, img);
}
```

Then your calling code will have to produce the correct name, such as:

```
SaveImage("c:\image.png", image);

SaveImage("c:\other.png", other);
```

Now, of course, if all you actually want is a unique name, rather than one that reflects the name of the variable in your code, then there are plenty of other possibilities, such as using a formatted string that contains a serial number, a random number, `tmpnam()` or other similar schemes.

Comment: Well like you as good as admitted yourself in the comments it was a *bad* answer. *That’s* why it got downvoted. This answer is better.